# Focus Urban/Planet 8 torque settings?

Tags: chain

[image]

These two bolts indicated by green arrows...what is the correct torque wrench setting please?

Comment: Have you already undone the bolts?  Could use your torque wrench to approximately measure the tightness of the bolt when undoing it really slowly.

Comment: Mmm. That is a good suggestion. However I have already undone them.

Comment: Did you check the manual?

Comment: Didn't get manual. Also have checked Focus website and no info. Have also emailed Focus manufacturer. Look at the design. I'd say this is critical to get correct. Usually I am skeptical re: torque settings on a push bike...but these things hold the entire rear mechanics to the frame. It's a sort of subframe.